# В чем разница / и // python?

Tags: python, математика

Новенький в программировании и толком не разобрался, а материала, как назло, нигде нет.

Comment: 5/2 - обычное деление, 2.5.   5//2 — целочисленное деление, с отбрасыванием дробной части. 2.

Answer (score 2):

/ - делит число на число и ты получаешь результат c дробной частью(если таковая имеется).
// - также делит число, но без дробной части.
В первом случае ты получишь формат float, во втором int

```
10/3 = 3.33
10//3 = 3
```

Comment: Может, все же int во втором, а float в первом?...

Comment: Да, точно. Я немного напутал